# React-Native "Network request failed" with form-data on Android

Tags: android, react-native, form-data

I'm currently trying to send images and data using form-data in a React-Native App. It actually works well on real iOs device but it doesn't on real Android device.

I'm getting "Network request failed" error with my Android device from the `console.log(error)` in the `.catch`.

Here is the code :

```
export(user, base64) {
   var formData = new FormData();
   formData.append("user", JSON.stringify(user));
   for (var key in base64) {
     formData.append("image" + [key], {
       uri: "data:image/png;base64," + base64[key],
       type: "image/png",
       name: "image" + [key]
     });
   }
   return new Promise((fulfill, reject) => {
     fetch("https://url.fr", {
       method: "POST",
       headers: {
         Accept: "application/json",
         "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
         userkey: userkey
       },
       body: formData
     })
       .then(response => {
         if (response.ok) {
           return response.json();
         } else {
           console.log(response);
           return {
             success: false
           };
         }
       })
       .then(responseJson => {
         fulfill(responseJson);
       })
       .catch(error => {
         console.log(error)
         // alert(error);
         reject(error);
       });
   });
}
```

If you have any idea of what goes wrong with my code, feel free to help me ;)

Thanks.

Comment: How you resolved it?